# Django queryset "using()" method for specifying database doesn't work on related_name queries

Tags: python, django

I've noticed something strange in Django that I haven't been able figure out. Let's say I have a Django application (I'm using 1.7) with two models like so:

```
class Bookstore(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Bookstore, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='books')
```

And then let's say I have two databases storing the data, perhaps a master-replica setup -- let's say the master is denoted as `default` in my settings file and the replica is `replica`. If I do the following query, I get an exception saying

> the current database router prevents this relation

```
store = Bookstore.objects.using('default').get(id=1)
first_book = store.books.using('replica').all().order_by('id')[0]
```

However, the following, which should be the same query, works just fine:

```
store = Bookstore.objects.using('default').get(id=1)
first_book = Book.objects.using('replica').filter(store=store).order_by('id')[0]
```

What's going on here? Is there anyway to use the related_name lookup like the first example but have it work properly? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to jump across the different databases?  I think the fact that you are doing so is what's creating your problem.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt yes, I do for my situation. Django seems to have no problem doing that with the second example, so I'm just wondering if there's a way to alter the queryset from my first example to do that same thing

Comment: So I've been skimming the internet in case you came back and said it did have to jump across the two DBs.  Unfortunately, I can't find any literature that lets you do such a thing.  I've seen examples where you could use `store.book_set.all()` and maybe you could try throwing in a `using()` but I would be surprised if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Look at SQL from first example (without `using()`):

```
SELECT "book"."id", "book"."title", "book"."store_id"
FROM "book" JOIN "bookstore" ON "book"."store_id" = "bookstore"."id"
WHERE "bookstore"."id" = 1
ORDER BY "book"."id"
LIMIT 1
```

Do You see the problem? You cannot do a `SELECT` on two databases.

And look at SQL from second example:

```
SELECT "book"."id", "book"."title", "book"."store_id"
FROM "book"
WHERE "book"."store_id" = 1
ORDER BY "book"."id"
LIMIT 1
```

Select data from one table.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm wondering if I'm already set on using the syntax from the first example (using the related name), is there anyway to modify the queryset object to have it query the database like the second example?

Comment: No. Second example is only way to do this.