# Django RestFramework return just last result after filtered

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

In my django project i use DjangoRestFramework for expose some API endpoint.
Now i am try to expose just the last result of a model after filtered the data.
Models:

```
class VarsResults(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_res = models.ForeignKey(Results, related_name="mainres", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    var_id = models.ForeignKey(ModbusVariable, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    var_val = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    var_val_conv = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    base_byte_order = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    var_hash = models.CharField(max_length=400)
```

serialyzers:

```
class VarsResultsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id_res = ResultsSerializer(read_only=True)
    var_id = ModvarSerializer(read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = VarsResults
    fields = ['id', 'id_res', 'var_id', 'var_val', 'var_conv', 'var_hash']
```

views.py

```
class VarResultsListLast(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = VarsResults.objects.using(random.choice(replica_list)).order_by('-id')[:1]
    serializer_class = VarsResultsSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    # paginator = None
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = {
        'id_res__id': ['exact'],
        'id_res__device': ['exact'],
        'id_res__unit__id': ['exact'],
        'id_res__proj_code': ['exact'],
        'var_id__var_group__short_name': ['exact'],
        'id_res__read_date': ['gte', 'lte', 'exact', 'gt', 'lt']
    }
    search_fields = ['id_res__id', 'id_res__unit__id', 'id_res__device', 'id_res__proj_code', 'id_res__read_date']
    ordering_fields = '__all__'
```

I create my queryset using `.order_by('-id')[:1]` for have just the last results but it works only if i don't use any filter (return the last result for the whole table), if i try to filter, for example using proj_code or somethin other filter i would to have in return just the last result from the filtered data, but i have:

(call for example: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/results_data_last/?id_res__proj_code=CR00069)

> AssertionError at /api/results_data_last/
> Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.

How can i execute my filtering options and then have in return just the last record (based on my model id)?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172828/django-queryset-using-method-for-specifying-database-doesnt-work-on-related

Comment: Thanks Siva but i cannot see the correlation, i am try to get last result of a filtered DjangoRestApi call but i cannot if filter. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By using `.last()` you can get the last record. Detailed in the docs

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#last

Comment: if i try last() i get the error: "rest_framework\backends.py", line 75, in Meta
    model = queryset.model
AttributeError: 'VarsResults' object has no attribute 'model'"

Comment: could you supply a stacktrace?
Also you are using ListView to retrieve a single object. For single objects i would recommend using DetailView.
You could also try to override the get_queryset method call the super and then at the end add the last.